# Can cpuminer-multi be used for solo CPU mining?

Tags: cpu-mining, mining-software

It seems that [Wolf's cpuminer-multi](https://github.com/wolf9466/cpuminer-multi) only allows to connect to a mining pool and can't be used for solo mining.

I've tried to use `-o daemon+tcp://:` to have it connect to `monerod` but it doesn't work.

**Can cpuminer-multi be configured to mine solo?**

Comment: anyone knows how to add code to my own miner, so i can compile it and solo mine, i have a personal test coin with argon2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolf0's CPU miner does not contain any code to support the fairly new daemon+tcp scheme, so cannot be used to solo mine.

However, you could setup your own private pool, and connect to it.If you disable payouts, this is as close to solo mining as you can get without being standard solo mining.

Answer (score 1):

You need my patched version of Wolf's miner https://github.com/hyc/cpuminer-multi/tree/daemon